# Rails: changing repetition into loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, loops

I'm trying to reduce repetition in my code. I have in several places this code (or variants thereof):

```
@articles1 = Article.all_articles(1).reverse
@articles2 = Article.all_articles(2).reverse
@articles3 = Article.all_articles(3).reverse
```

Is a way to change it to something like:

```
3.times do |i|
  @articles[i+1] = Article.all_articles(i+1).reverse
end
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
@articles = (1..3).to_a.map { |i| Article.all_articles(i).reverse }
```

Comment: I get an uninitialised constant error? `uninitialized constant DocumentsController::Articles`.